# Arrange data in tabular format

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have input file as

```
cell 1
Input A1;
Input A2;
Input B;
Output Z;
Type comb
Function  ((A1 A2) B) ;
cell 2
Input A1;
Input A2;
Input B;
Input C;
Output Z;
Type comb
Function  (((A1+A2)+B)+C) ;
```

Can i represent above in table form as

```
cell    Input       Output   Type  Function 
1       A1,A2,B     Z        comb  ((A1 A2) B
2       A1,A2,B,C   Z        comb  (((A1+A2)+B)+C)
```

Using `column` command i am getting `cell,input,output, Type, function`  parameters in row but i want then in column form.

I also tried using for loop and grepping each parameter and assigning it to a variable and printing that variable using echo command but the output is listing all cells together, all inputs together etc. Its not displaying in proper format.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: I tried using for loop and grepping each parameter and assigning it to a variable and printing that variable using echo command but the output is listing all cells together,  all inputs together etc. Its not displaying in proper format.

Comment: Sure, thanks for letting know your efforts, please do add them in your question, there is nothing wrong or right, we all are here to learn, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
  print "cell\tInput\toutput\ttype\tfunction"
}
{
  sub(/;+/,"")
}
/^cell/{
  if(value["cell"]){
    print value["cell"],value["input"],value["output"],value["type"],value["func"]
    delete value
  }
  value["cell"]=$NF
  next
}
/^Input/{
  value["input"]=(value["input"]?value["input"] ",":"")$NF
  next
}
/^Output/{
  value["output"]=(value["output"]?value["output"] ",":"")$NF
  next
}
/^Type/{
  value["type"]=(value["type"]?value["type"] ",":"")$NF
  next
}
/^Function/{
  sub(/[^ +]* +/,"")
  value["func"]=(value["func"]?value["func"] ",":"")$0
  next
}
END{
  if(value["cell"]){
    print value["cell"],value["input"],value["output"],value["type"],value["func"]
  }
}' Input_file | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
cell  Input      output  type  function
1     A1,A2,B    Z       comb  ((A1 A2) B)
2     A1,A2,B,C  Z       comb  (((A1+A2)+B)+C)
```